# How to set default value in @Entity object field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My entity has field that has one to one connection with another table. How can I set default value for that field. I was trying to to something like this

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 5")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Admin admin;
```

But I get this error

```
@Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne
```

Is there a way to achive this without altering table in SQL?

EDIT:

Changed some stuff around. Now I have code like this.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint(20) DEFAULT 5")
private Admin admin;
```

I also added `@DynamicInsert` and `@DynamicUpdate` but it still doesn't work. I also want to note that those Admin objects already exist in DB and I don't want to create them again.

Comment: do u have ``@JoinColumn(name = "xxx")`` ?

Comment: So Admin table PK by default is 5?

Comment: you should set this in your constructor by loading Admin object from the database as 5 might not be the pk in every environment.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar I would prefer not to load it from database.

Comment: @Virx that's your decision, hard coding information isn't recommended. Anyway good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If one Admin (5) can have many Entities you better use **@ManyToOne** relationship, which might look like:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private Admin admin;
```

And each time you create entity you better fetch from database so you will not get LazyLoadingException, something like this:

```
Admin admin = adminService.getDefaultAdmin(); //returns 'select a from Admin a where id = 5'
Entity entity = new Entity();
..fill the fields
entity.setAdmin(admin);
entityService.save(entity);
```

This way you will make sure you have accessed the latest version of admin so you will not override any field of admin or you dont have to worry for cascading.